# KnockoutJS validation plugin on viewmodel components

Tags: validation, knockout.js

My viewmodel has a `ko.observable` members that store dialog state objects. Each dialog object has all sorts of members corresponding to input fields in a dialog. I would like to add validation to the dialogs using the KnockoutJS validation plugin.

I don't, however, want to add validation to my entire view model, but rather just to my dialogs. When I tried extending the dialogs like this:

```
    this.dialog = ko.observable(new RegistrationDialog(self)).extend({validatable: true});
```

things didn't work right: the isValid() and errors() methods were not defined, and validation wasn't working properly. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/t9zLH/6/) to illustrate this. When I press the start button, the dialog opens (pardon the lack of CSS), but pressing enter doesn't generate any error messages. email validation also fails to work, showing the message 'true is not a proper email address.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the [documentation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation):

```
this.dialog = ko.validatedObservable(new RegistrationDialog(this));
```

Then fix some bugs in your fiddle:

- data-blind
- click handler on the form (instead of submit, I assume)
- on the register button you have `enable: isValid` which should be `enable: isValid()` (I also removed the click binding because of fixing the form submit binding)

I think that was it. [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/t9zLH/14/)

Comment: Can you explain why pressing the enter key at an empty dialog does not trigger any validation? I have having problems with this as well.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the validation plugin has any built-in support for forms and submits. I got it to work only with a bit of a hack (when there is no enabled submit button, pressing enter didn't attempt to submit the form..), adding a hidden submit button. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/t9zLH/17/

Comment: ok, that's a nice idea! Any thoughts on why the email error message reports `true` as the email address?

Comment: As John says, this is a bug with the validation plugin, I'd go with his workaround of using `email: 'This'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/t9zLH/8/

I added an errors group inside and check it before allowing your register method to succeed, otherwise I show the errors.

Comment: and if you want the isValid to work add this to RegistrationDialog:


this.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.errors().length == 0;
});

Comment: Sorry about the typos in my example; it was a rather rushed cut&paste job. The example you provided works much better than mine did, but it still exhibits the odd error message for email validation, and won't handle the enter key if I implement the `enable` binding on the button. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/PdAtG/) the new example, which includes @antishok's helpful suggestions as well. I had tried the `ko.validatedObservable` earlier, and that didn't work at the time. Not sure what I had screwed up!

Comment: The email message issue is a known bug.  For a quick workaround you can used this: email: 'This' (rather than email: true).  It still evaluates to true, so the validation runs, and 'This' will be added t o the error giving a message of 'This is not a valid email address'. - http://jsfiddle.net/PdAtG/1/

Comment: Oh... and for enter key handling I have found the [executeOnEnter](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/10/11/knockoutjs-custom-binding-for-invoking-an-action-with-enter-key.aspx) custom binding useful.